# Jenkins slave and Maven Project

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have problem with understanding how jenkins slaves are working. I have a master jenkins and a node defined as slave. I have a Maven project that I want to run on slave but having the report available on Jenkins Master.

Should I have Maven installed on Master or on Slave or both?  Do I keep the Maven project on Slave or Master or both? I think it should be both but I can not understand why?

Comment: The slave is where the mvn command is executed ....

Comment: if thats the case why should I have Maven installed on the Master ?

Comment: I had a similar issue and commented on this here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24508607/1279002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using slaves, you just have to ensure that each slave has external tools installed (Maven in your case), and properly configured (available in path, custom settings.xml if any, etc.)

To avoid having to bind a job to a unique slave, an obvious best practice is to have all your slave configured alike (i.e. all linux slaves with all needed tools, same for windows slaves, etc.)

Once all your tools are available on each slave, Jenkins takes care of running the project on an available node (master or a slave). Monitoring, log tail, build history and so on... is transparently available to the user, whatever the node used.

You don't even need to care about plugins, they are automatically available to the slaves once installed on the master.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized that Maven and other tools must be installed on both Master and Slave unless I'm not able to define a tool only for the slave! In my case I actually need to limit the build of a project to specific slave and I was able to assign that project to one slave. The point I still understand is that if there is Maven on Master and Slave, which Maven is actually building the project, are they communicating to each other? or its only simple client/server connection by Jenkins which run on the slave and bring back the results to the Master?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any `MAVEN or Jenkins` component on slave. When you create the slave then, It gives you the option to launch it as `JNLP(Java Network Launch Protocol)` file. 
Save this file and copy it to slave machine and launch it. Only prequisite is to have JAVA installed on slave machine.

On launching it will establish connection with Master. I am using selenium grid like that. I am not aware of your use case. This may help.